# .htaccess rewrite to subdirectory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Trying to get

```
www.domain.com.br
```

to go directly to

```
www.domain.com.br/masterweb
```

I'm using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /masterweb[L]
```

which works perfectly.
The problem is that I don't want to show the /masterweb. All website is in one folder call masterweb and the public_html folder will have another projects.

How can I redirect and remove /masterweb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to  use two diffrent rules , one for redirecting new url to old (/masterweb=>/) and the other for rewriting old url to the new one (/=>/masterweb/) :

```
RewriteEngine on
#redirect /masterweb/ to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /masterweb/\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R]
#rewrite / to /masterweb/
RewriteRule ^$ /masterweb/ [L]
```